# Refreshing div without reloading not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm "fighting" with this for hours now, I hope you could help me with the solution. So I've got a basic form with an empty div that will be then filled:

```
<form method='post' action='/shoutek.php'>
<input type='text' id='shout_tresc' name='shout_tresc' class='shout_tresc' />
    <input type='submit' id='dodaj' value='Dodaj' />
</form>

<div class='shoutboxtresc' id='shout'></div>
<span class='loader'>Please wait...</span>
```

The shoutek.php contains the queries to do after submission of the form and functions to populate the div.

Here goes my jquery:

```
$(function() {

    $(\"#dodaj\").click(function() {
        // getting the values that user typed

        var shout_tresc = $(\"#shout_tresc\").val();
        // forming the queryString
        var data            = 'shout_tresc='+ shout_tresc;

        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: \"POST\",
            url: \"shoutek.php\",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
                $(\"#shout\").toggle(500, function(){
                $('.loader').show();    
                    $(this).html(html).toggle(500);
                    $(\"#shout_tresc\").val(\"\");
                $('.loader').hide();        
                });
                 return false;
          }
        });   

    });
});
```

The problem in that is that it directs me to shoutek.php, so it does not refresh the div in ajax.

As you can see, I used return false; - i also tried the event.preventDefault(); function - it did not help. What is the problem and how to get rid of it? Will be glad if you could provide me with some solutions.

**EDIT**

Guys, what I came up with actually worked, but let me know if that's a correct solution and will not cause problems in the future. From the previous code (see Luceous' answer) i deleted

```
$(function() {
```

(and of course it's closing tags) and I completely got rid of the:

```
<form method='post' action='/shoutek.php'>
```

Leaving the input "formless". Please let me know if it is a good solution - it works after all.

Comment: Your solutions is also possible, you are not using the form at all anyway. But consider whether your solution will work if javascript is disabled (something I'll never consider anyway, but you might need to depending on your visitors and their browsers capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $("#dodaj").click(function(e) {
        // prevents form submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // getting the values that user typed

        var shout_tresc = $("#shout_tresc").val();
        // forming the queryString
        var data            = 'shout_tresc='+ shout_tresc;

        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shoutek.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
                $("#shout").toggle(500, function(){
                $('.loader').show();    
                    $(this).html(html).toggle(500);
                    $("#shout_tresc").val("");
                $('.loader').hide();        
                });
                 return false;
          }
        });   

    });
});
```

For readability I removed your escapes. You've missed the preventDefault which prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: I've already mentioned that i tried with prevenDefault. It's still not working.

Comment: I'm not seeing your code for the preventDefault. But that's the only method. So is your ajax being called at all?

Comment: Well, as it appeared to me, it is not. But why? I just have the mentioned above code in <script> tags in the footer, and jquery of course.

Comment: What i tried now: i put the .loader function to be fired after clicking, not inside the other functions, and it DIDNT work. What i tried next is I put the whole code to the header of my website - the .loader function right after clicking started to work, but this page reloading still occurs.

Comment: If you are not parsing the javascript in `echo ""` or so, why do you escape the double quotes? Using them in your way only creates errors. Did you check your console (f12 in chrome).

Comment: I am parsing it in echo "", sorry, forgot to mention. Please look at my edit and let me know what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action on submit button click:

```
$("#dodaj").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // your code
}
```